# Can we upgrade to Spring 5 even if we are not planning to move to Java 8+ currently?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, upgrade, java-9

I have an application built in **JDK 8** and **Spring 4.x**. I would like to move from Spring 4.x to Spring 5.x?

While going through this link "[What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x)", it seems like Spring 5.x is mainly focusing on supporting JDK 8+ (9, 10, 11 etc.).

I understand that it is not saying anywhere that it will stop supporting JDK 8 related feature but just wanted to understand if it is completely fine to move to Spring 5.x while still being on JDK 8? Can someone please share their views here?

Comment: If you are asking for backward compatibility, their documentation doesn't stop you from upgrading. Besides its always a good idea to be using the head unless you find a reason not to! (which shall be reported to the library owners to call it out otherwise.) Aside: Voted as opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 5.x requires JDK 8 or higher. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-51

So you can migrate without any issues. In fact, I am using it with the same combination.

Comment: First-line already mentioned in the question. The next should rather be a comment.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your time. Will move to Spring 5.x then.